# Is it possible to connect ssh enabled MySql database to azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using a virtual machine to get ssh enabled MySql database(on-premise data)and trying to copy on the cloud using Data Factory. Is it possible to connect ssh enabled MySql database to Azure data factory?

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to connect directly. There is a workaround through which we create a tunnel using "bitvise" for connection.You can find complete solution in the link given below.
https://www.neenopal.com/ssh_enable_adf_copy.html

Comment: can you share the complete solution for connecting Azure data factory to tunnelled mysql database? the shared link does not exist anymore. Thank you!